# Stack Exchange Android App doesn't show Favorite Tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, tag-watching

Stack Exchange Android App
Version 1.0.63

I recently downloaded and started using the Stack Exchange Mobile App for Android. And while it's a great app, overall, and I quite like it for the basics, it seems to be lacking one feature I absolutely love about the website (and even the mobile site): **favorite tags**.

Typically, when browsing sites on the Stack Exchange network (we'll use Stack Overflow for this example), I use the Favorite Tags feature to navigate around. I click the `c#` tag to be navigated to a filtered view of questions relating to `C#`, I click the `.net` tag to be navigated to a filtered view of questions relating to `.NET`, etc. I have four in specific that I use **constantly** (`c#`, `.net`, `asp.net`, `vb.net`).

On the mobile app, there's no easy way to access these tags. The best I've found is one of two options:

1. Go to `Stack Overflow` in the sites -> click the header (`Stack Overflow`) -> click `Tags` in the header drop-down -> click `c#` in the list. If I wish to switch to the `vb.net` tag, I have to repeat all but the first step of this procedure.
2. Go to `Stack Overflow` in the sites -> click the (I assume `filter` or `sort`) dropdown right of the search bar -> click `Unanswered (my tags)`. This procedure, however, does not at all get me what I want.

It would be nice if there would be an easier way to get to my favorite tags, rather than going through the first procedure. (As that is the only one that really gets me what I want.) I don't personally need the `edit` feature of them, only the ability to quickly change between them.

The **Tags** dropdown menu would not be so bad, and would even be the preferred place to put it, if my favorite tags would appear at the top. Even that would be a **huge** improvement.

Answer (score 1):

While it would definitely be useful to have access to your favorite tags for easier navigation, there is a third option available. You can type tags directly into the search box itself, simply wrap them in brackets, e.g., `[c#]`, `[.net]`, `[asp.net]`, etc. That will have a similar effect as clicking on a tag on the desktop/mobile sites.

Comment: Yes, but that defeats the purpose of my favourite tags.